# calculating the orientation of an object

Tags: matrices, rotations, quaternions, orientation

If you have a rotation matrix (or an attitude/direct cosine matrix, which are all synonyms). This matrix actually transforms vectors from one reference frame to another. But if your goal is to know/calculate the orientation of an object. Why do you need to be able to transform those vectors in order to know the orientation?

I initially thought that this rotation matrix was an absolute representation of your orientation, but appearantly it's not.

example of an algorithm using this principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know the orientation of an object, you need to first privilege a basis to examine the object with respect to. You need some kind of axes to use as a reference point. If you calculate the rotation matrix with respect to am that basis, it allows you to calculate the orientation of the object.

It should t surprise you that knowing orientation and knowing rotation matrices are the same. After all, the orientation is a measure of an amount of rotation. The rotation matrix you find above is the one that transforms from the basis to the orientation, which is how we specify an orientation.

Comment: (+1) Put another way: The set $SO(3)$ of rotations (i.e., the set of rotation matrices) comprise a group, but the set of orientations is only an $SO(3)$-torsor. If we want to give a correspondence between orientations and rotations, we must fix a preferred orientation to identify with the identity of the group.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong: Ok so the rotation matrix is a transformation of the three vectors forming the basis to the vectors which are attached the body frame itself. So this means the RM actually contains the angles between the vectors attached to the body and the basis vectors. And by knowing these angles you actually know orientation. Is this correct?

Comment: this explanation applied to TRIAD: you have the vectors $\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2$, which are issued by measurements of varous sensors. The other vectors $\vec{R}_1$ and $ \vec{R}_2$ are some base vectors that never change. Their position is determined by "the laws of astronomy". This means you have (once you cross multiplied everything) 2 3x3 matrices. The rotation matrix A then only represents the angles between e.g the x-vector of the body reference frame and the x-angle from another reference frame?

Comment: Yes. If you rewrite your rotation matrix in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ the argument of the trig functions is the angle of rotation.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO%283%29 Under "axis of rotation"

Comment: But I suupose that when using data from sensors, in order to form a vector it has to be normalized in some way? example; you have 3 sunsensors, one in the x, another in th y and z direction. By measuring the amount of light you can already know you orientation to the sun. Lets say you get the vector [100,0,0].  (it measures on a scale from 0 to 100). another vector can be obtained by measuring the magnetic field. And you get the vector [35,4;0;0] (it measures from 0 to 40). So my question: as you can see the maximum value of one measurement doesn't equal the maximum of the other (100 <-> 40).

Comment: Does this matter? Another question. I know you can construct vectors based on the measurements (those are attached to the body reference frame). But what about the other vectors, which are related to another reference frame $\vec{R}_1$ and $\vec{R}_12$. How are those vectors constructed?